# PHP - using a line from a text file in an IF statement

Tags: php

I am trying to get a PHP file to read a specific line from a text file and then use that line in a string comparison for an if statement.
The second line in the textfield will always have one of two different values. Either `&activeGame=0` or `&activeGame=1`.

The textfile:

```
boardarray=["NV", "SB", "VB", "NV"]  
&activeGame=1  
&activePlayer=V
```

The PHP-file:

```
$theFile = "test.txt";
$line = file($theFile);
echo $line[1]; //This will output "&activeGame=1" without quotation marks

if ($line[1] == "&activeGame=1") {
    echo "The game is active";
} else {
    echo "The game is not active";
}
```

Since `echo $line[1]` outputs `&activeGame=1` I know that the PHP script can read the data from the text file.
The problem is that the if function will echo `"The game is not active"` and I cant figure out why.

**EDIT**
**SOLUTION:**

```
$theFile = "test.txt";
$line = file($theFile);
echo $line[1]; //This will output "&activeGame=1" without quotation marks

if (trim($line[1]) == "&activeGame=1") { 
    echo "The game is active";
} else {
    echo "The game is not active";
}
```

The trim function on row 5 is what was missing.

Comment: Maybe you have whitespaces on the value that's coming from the .txt file

Comment: good answers below... A side suggestion is to use single quotes (not evaluated) vs double quotes (evaluated).  `if ($line[1] == '&activeGame=1'){`.  In this case it doesn't impact the result.

Comment: Make sure they are the same comparing them using `var_dump()` on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Problem** was if you echo $line[1] then its value is **"&activeGame=1 "** ( Notice the whitespace at end . and the optimal Solution Code that will give you desired output is as below

```
<?php
$theFile = "test.txt";
$line = file($theFile);
echo trim($line[1]); //This will output "&activeGame=1" without     quotation marks

$a=trim($line[1]);

$truestr="&activeGame=1";


if ($a == $truestr) {
    echo "The game is active";
} else {
    echo "The game is not active";
}
?>
```

OUTPUT
'&activeGame=1'The game is active

Comment: this will always return true as written

Comment: yes i was only telling about space and for true condition for proper working let me update the code again

Comment: fixes the logic problem, yes.  though this `$falsestr="&activeGame=0 ";` is redundant as I would imagine that anything not matching true is false (per your else statement) so why assign a `$falsestr`

Comment: @Dave yes you are right . It may be useful in further code but looks redundant here . Updated the code

Comment: @Heemanshu Bhalla - I had noticed that there was a space in the end of the line[1], but when i tried to compare it with "&activeGame=1 " (with a space) I still got "The game is not active".  But the trim part solved the problem! I have updated the original post so that future Googlers can get help as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that every line of file ends with `\n`.

You can see it if you `var_dump($line[1])` instead of echo it.

So real value for `&activeGame=1` is `&activeGame=1\n`.
That's definitely not equals `&activeGame=1`.

So, before comparing - use `trim` function:

```
$theFile = "test.txt";
$line = file($theFile);
echo $line[1]; //This will output "&activeGame=1" without quotation marks

$line_one = trim($line[1]);
if ($line_one == "&activeGame=1") {
    echo "The game is active";
} else {
    echo "The game is not active";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `parse_str` this way even if there are more variables on that line you can always get that value.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

```
$theFile = "test.txt";
$line = file($theFile);
parse_str($line[1],$output);

if ($output['activeGame'] == 1) {
    echo "The game is active";
} else {
    echo "The game is not active";
}
```